# Lower bound for worst case running time for k-clique problem

Tags: algorithms, graphs, clique

A naive algorithm for determining whether a graph with $|V|$ vertices has a clique of size $k$ is to list all $k$-subsets of $V$, and check each one to
see whether it forms a clique. Why is the running time of this algorithm $\Omega(k^{2}{|V| \choose k})$? Specifically, where are we getting $k^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $k^2$ comes from the check that a set of size $k$ is a clique.

You will need to verify that each node has all other nodes as neighbors, which takes $\Omega(k)$ time to verify that. There are $k$ such nodes, for a total of $\Omega(k^2)$ time.